# Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 in controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this error in two of my tests:

```
test "should create question" do
  assert_difference('Question.count') do
    post :create, question: { question: 'apple', answer: "good", holder_id: 2}
  end
end

test "should not create question" do
  invalid_answer = "a" * 145 
  assert_difference('Question.count',0) do
    post :create, question: { answer: invalid_answer }
  end
  assert_template 'new'
end
```

My create action

```
#create action
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @holder = Holder.find_by_id(@question.holder.id)
  if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Question Saved"
      redirect_to holder_path(@question.holder_id)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

The stack trace shows it is on the create line both times. But, how come I get the `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id` error?

Do I need to create an object first and then pass that in to the post create?

Comment: What does your create action look like in the controller? Somewhere you're calling `.id` on something that hasn't been created yet. Perhaps you do something like `@question.type = QuestionType.normal.id` - i.e, you use "seed" data, and it's not loaded? If you post the create action it would help us out.

Comment: There it is: `@holder = Holder.find_by_id(@question.holder***.id***)`. Later on, you use @question.holder_id, which does not raise an exception. However, it seems like you would like to prevent creation of questions that do not have a holder, e.g. by a validation. Rep to @MrDanA - you should post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @holder   = Holder.find_by_id(@question.holder.id)
```

Yes you were right, you need to create the Holder instance before running this test.

But why do you create all the ivars, do you need them in new?

If not it seems the code can be dryed up to

```
def create
  question = Question.new(params[:question])
  if question.save
    flash[:success] = "Question Saved"
      redirect_to holder_path(question.holder) # but some checks are in order here, no?
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

HTH
Robert